# Use trycatch to run on next loops when detect error

Tags: r

Trying to write a trycatch function to detect an error. But the loop would not continue run after it has detected an error.

```
for(number in 1:10){
    tryCatch({
      user_link = suppressMessages(remoteDriver$findElement(using = 'css selector', x[number]))
    }, error = function(e){ user_link = NA})

    user_link = as.character(user_link$getElementText())

    commentdf1 = data.frame(user_link)
    commentdf = rbind(commentdf,commentdf1)
  }
```

I'm expecting to have 10 informations while running on the loop. And if is an error to input `user_link = NA`

Comment: Please post error message. This subsequent line will error out if `user_link` is NA: `as.character(user_link$getElementText())`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying to find an alternative to this kind of usage of `tryCatch`. It can make code much more difficult to read, make unexpected errors almost undetectable and in the case that any package used within `tryCatch` changes it's code, your code will simply stop working, while yielding no distinguishable error.

That said your problem is not in the `tryCatch` function, but in the call that follows directly after `user_link$getElementText()`, which will output a different error, if `tryCatch` function results in an error.

There are a few ways to get around this. The simplest one is just skipping the iteration using the `next` operator. In this case it is likely wise to include which iterations succeeded in the `data.frame`.

```
for(number in 1:10){
    if(isFALSE(
        tryCatch({
        user_link = suppressMessages(
            remoteDriver$findElement(using = 'css selector', x[number])
        )}, error = function(e) FALSE)
        )
      ) next

    user_link = as.character(user_link$getElementText())

    #Include iteration so we can see which succeeded and which did not.
    commentdf1 = data.frame(user_link, iteration = i)
    commentdf = rbind(commentdf,commentdf1)
  }
```

Alternative to including the iteration you could create the entire `data.frame` before-hand, and impute the succesful iterations using `commentdf[i, ] <- user_link`, which would speed up your implementation as well (quite noticable if you have anything more than 20 iterations).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, its work for me now. May I check how can I input 'NA' if I detect an error?

Comment: Two easy methods is to 1) pre-create the  `data.frame` and insert the rows ( eg. something like `commentdf <- data.frame(c1 = rep(NA, 10), ....)`, using proper columns and dimensions, and then insert as in my answer.) or include `user_link = as.character(user_link$getElementText())` in the first part of the `tryCatch` call itself (in your own code). You will have to ensure that the number of columns in `commentdf1` always match the number of columns in `commentdf`. Remember to upvote and/or mark the answer as answering the qusetion, to help others with similar problems find an answer. :-)

Comment: or you can grep the error message, catch specific errors, and let other unexpected ones throw an error `tryCatch(stop('catch this'), error = function(e) if (grepl('catch', e$message)) NA else e)`

Comment: @rawr, this **should** not work, as the reason for failure **should** come from the subsequent call for `.$getElementText()`. The problem at hand is that @Geo is wishing to get the `NA` value into his `data.frame`, which requires a bit of moving around in the code itself.

Comment: I am referring to this `It can make code much more difficult to read, make unexpected errors almost undetectable and in the case that any package used within tryCatch changes it's code, your code will simply stop working, while yielding no distinguishable error`

Comment: Now that makes alot more sense. Context helps.